# How to change view on midnight in WidgetKit, SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have a code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let entry: LessonWidgetEntry
    private static let url: URL = URL(string: "widgetUrl")!
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch entry.state {
            case .none:
                ProgramNotStartedView()
            case .currentLesson(let lesson):
                LessonView(lesson: lesson, imageName: entry.program?.imageName)
            case .lessonCompleted(let lesson):
                LessonCompletedView(lesson: lesson)
            case .programCompleted:
                ProgramCompletedView()
            }
        }.widgetURL(ContentView.url)
    }
}
```

At midnight LessonCompletedView should change to LessonView, but I am not sure how to do that.
Any ideas on how to change views on midnight from the widget?

Comment: Yes. Thank you @pawello2222 ! You always help me with the widgets :D I am still mostly using swift, and only used swiftui for the widgets, so I still have some issues with that time to time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Assuming you have an Entry (in your app you have `entry.state...` but for this example I used a simplified version):

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let lesson: Lesson
}
```

2. Setup your TimelineProvider to refresh timeline after the next midnight:

```
struct SimpleProvider: TimelineProvider {
    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
        let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

        let entries = [
            SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, lesson: Lesson()) // pass the lesson here
        ]

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

In the TimelineProvider you may pass any lesson you want (depending on the day or the previous lesson - it's up to you). You may also pass a variable to an Entry indicating whether the lesson is completed.

By setting the `.after(nextMidnight)` policy you indicate when do you want your Timeline (and therefore you Widget View) to be reloaded.

Comment: what is `entryDate` in this context?

Comment: @RichardRobinson Good catch, thanks. It's the date when you want to show an entry, so in this case it can just be the current date.