# WidgetKit: Refresh data based on a certain time?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

Is it possible to dynamically update a Widget / show a View based on a specific time?

For example, something like that the following code:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
    

    // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
    let currentDate = Date()
   
    // Get specific date / time to update then compare it to system's current time. 
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.hour = 12
    components.month = 0
    let midnight = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    

    if midnight == currentDate {
    
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), text: "",  configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
        entries.append(entry)
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
        
    } else {
        
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 6 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
        
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, text: update,  configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please add more information. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was wondering if it it's possible to have the Widget "reset" / present a new entry View at a certain time?  For example, if 'text' field gets updated throughout the day, is it possible to have its value be automatically cleared at a certain time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change view on midnight in WidgetKit, SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64209612/8697793)

Comment: This might also help you: [SwiftUI iOS 14 Widget CountDown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64155800/8697793)

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I want to update widget 6am to 6pm. Any suggestions?
@pawello2222